# convert HashMap to JavaBean instance given javabean class

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

is there a utility out there for creating a bean (which has simple String attributes whose name match with HashMap *keys* ) given bean class as input along with properly set hashmap?

thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) should be able to help you - since it's used for "bean" operations by many other frameworks. A **["DynaBean"](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html)** looks close to that.

Comment: Hi, org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap did the trick for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to go for [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). I have been using it (for 3 years) for map-bean transformation and it works great. It also integrates well with Spring

Answer (score -1):

Try to use mapstruct:

```
@Mapping(target = "beanField", source = "mapKey")
JavaBean toCustomer(Map<String, Object> map);
```

https://mapstruct.org/news/2021-07-18-mapstruct-1_5_0_Beta1-is-out/#mapping-from-map-to-bean